# Solr: To get all records

Tags: solr, solrj, solrnet, solrcloud

I am trying to upgrade my Solr 4.x version to 5.2.1 Solrcloud implementation. I had written following code to get all the results from Sorl query which works well in Solr single instance mode.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addSort("agent_status", ORDER.desc);
query.addFilterQuery("account_id:\"" + accountId + "\"");
query.set("rows", Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

But code will not work well in SolrCloud implemenation.It throws following exception.

```
2015-08-14 16:44:45,648 ERROR [solr.core.SolrCore] - [http-8080-8] : java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:58)
at org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.<init>(PriorityQueue.java:39)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.ShardFieldSortedHitQueue.<init>(ShardDoc.java:113)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.mergeIds(QueryComponent.java:972)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleRegularResponses(QueryComponent.java:750)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.handleResponses(QueryComponent.java:729)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:388)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
```

I found that it is failing because of `query.set("rows", Integer.MAX_VALUE)` statement.People suggested me to use pagination.
But, I can not afford doing pagination as there will be too many changes  at UI side.

There is one more way where I can first query with some small number & get total number of documents using `response.getResults().getNumFound()` method & try setting that value to `setRows` method.But this approach will increase one more call to server.

Is there any other way I can solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039778/how-to-get-all-results-from-solr-query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385168/get-all-the-results-from-solr-without-10-as-limit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662060/in-solr-is-there-an-way-to-fetch-all-results-from-a-query-something-like-start-0

Answer (score 1):

You can always set your rows to be a large value that would encompass your results. Integer.MAX_VALUE will not work due to the size limits of Java Arrays (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038392/do-java-arrays-have-a-maximum-size)) and the Lucene Priority Queue (see [lines 42 - 58)](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_5_2_1/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/util/PriorityQueue.java).

[Solr-534](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-534) requested to have essentially what your asking for; there is some good conversation about why and why-not such a feature would be good.

A better question might be how many documents can the UI hold without becoming unusable?  However many documents that is, would be a good value for your query to return.